# Generating repeated measures dataset

Tags: r

I'm looking to generate a dataset in R for a repeated measures model and I'm not sure where to start.

The outcome of interest is continuous between 0-100. This is for a two arm trial (say groups "a" and "b"), with 309 participants in each arm. Each participant is assessed at baseline, then fortnightly for one year (27 total assessments). There will be loss to followup and withdrawals over the year (~30% after one year), and participants may miss individual assessments at random.

For now, I am assuming the standard deviation is the same at each timepoint, and for both arms (11). The mean will change over time. I'm working on the assumption each participant's score is correlated with their baseline measurement.

How can I generate this dataset? I'm intending to compare repeated measures regression methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following fulfils your requirements. It works by taking the cumulative sum of samples from a normal distribution over 27 weeks and converting these into a logistic scale between 0 and 100 (so that the maximum / minimum scores are never breached). It uses `replicate` to do this for 309 participants. It then simulates 30% drop outs by choosing random participants and a random week, following which their measurements are all `NA`. It also adds in some random missing weeks for the rest of the participants. The result is pivoted into long format to allow for easier analysis.

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)

# Generate correlated scores for 309 people over 27 visits
df <- setNames(cbind(data.frame(ID = 1:309, t(replicate(309, {
  x <- cumsum(rnorm(27, 0.05, 0.1))
  round(100 * exp(x)/(1 + exp(x)))
  })))), c('ID', paste0('Visit_', 1:27)))

# Model dropouts at 30% rate
dropout <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 309, TRUE, prob = c(0.7, 0.3))
df[cbind(which(!dropout), sample(2:28, sum(!dropout), TRUE))] <- NA
df <- as.data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, function(x) ifelse(is.na(cumsum(x)), NA,x))))

# Add random missing visits
df[cbind(sample(309, 100, TRUE), sample(2:28, 100, TRUE))] <- NA

df <- pivot_longer(df, -ID, names_to = 'Week', values_to = 'Score') %>%
  mutate(Week = 2 * (as.numeric(gsub('\\D+', '', Week)) - 1))
```

Our data frame now looks like this:

```r
head(df)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>      ID  Week Score
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     0    50
#> 2     1     2    51
#> 3     1     4    51
#> 4     1     6    56
#> 5     1     8    58
#> 6     1    10    57
```

And we can see the scores drift upward over time (since we set a small positive mu on our `rnorm` when creating the scores.

```r
lm(Score ~ Week, data = df)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = Score ~ Week, data = df)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)         Week  
#>     52.2392       0.5102
```

We can plot and see the overall shape of the scores and their spread:

```
ggplot(df, aes(Week, Score, group = ID)) + geom_line(alpha = 0.1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>